# Specifying --host1 as localhost with port 8983 in autobench

Tags: localhost, autobench

```
I am using autobench for benchmarking in ubuntu 8.10
```

**autobench --single_host --host1 localhost --uri1 /solr/admin --low_rate 20 --high_rate 200 --rate_step 20 --num_call 10 --num_conn 5000 --timeout 5 --file bench1.tsv**

This is the command which I gave.  It is taking the default port as 80 and the number of replies and requests are as shown below

```
**Errors: total 5000 client-timo 0 socket-timo 0 connrefused 5000 connreset 0
  Errors: fd-unavail 0 addrunavail 0 ftab-full 0 other 0
  Zero replies received, test invalid: rate 20
  httperf --timeout=5 --client=0/1 --server=localhost --port=80 --uri=/solr/admin  --rate=40 --send-buffer=4096 --recv-buffer=16384 --num-conns=5000 --num-calls=10
   Maximum connect burst length: 4
   Total: connections 5000 requests 0 replies 0 test-duration 124.976 s**
```

But, I want the port to be 8983.  In all the examples that I have seen in the autobench tutorial, --host1 is a website (such as, www.test.com).  Can anyone suggest how to use localhost taking the port as 8983?  Thanks, in advance.

Comment: The problem got resolved by adding --port1 8983

Answer (score 1):

```
man autobench
```

Then you will see

> --port1 port
>                 The port number on which host1's server is listening